# Update or updating of <something>...?

Tags: grammar

Can anyone give me a clarification on this sentence please:

> Some administrations request additional documents for the **update** of your civil status.
>
> Some administrations request additional documents for the **updating** of your civil status.

Answer (score 1):

Update = the event
Updating = the performance of that action

So they both could work.  "...for the updating of..." sounds clunky, and it would more likely be said as "for updating your civil status".  The first one sounds more like they're going to toss those documents into a pile/queue for later updates; the second one sounds more like they will perform the updates themselves.  But the grammar's not definitive -- that's just a slight difference in feel.